# What is better way to say about a future plans?

Tags: sentence-choice, future-time

I have a dialogue and need to complete the answer.

> A: Do you fancy playing tennis at 12 o’clock tomorrow?
>
> B: I’m sorry, I can’t join you at that time

Which is the most preferable answer and which are incorrect?

- I have lunch with Mary.
- I’m having lunch with Mary.
- I’m going to have lunch with Mary.
- I will have lunch with Mary.
- I’ll be having lunch with Mary.

Comment: Which among these do you think is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I’m having lunch with Mary" is the most natural answer.  From the context, it will be obvious that you mean you'll be having lunch with her tomorrow at 12.

"I have lunch with Mary" is correct but makes lunch sound like either a regular event or an important scheduled event.

"I’m going to have lunch with Mary" is a statement of intent but doesn't make clear whether you've made arrangements with her yet.

"I will have lunch with Mary" is correct but sounds a little odd, unless it is either a statement of determination or a reminder to the other person of something they should already know.

"I’ll be having lunch with Mary" is correct and a very close second to "I'm having lunch with Mary".

Answer (score 0):

Future: "I’m going to have lunch with Mary.", "I will have lunch with Mary."

Present Simple: I have lunch with Mary. (Means that I usually have lunch with her. every day or almost every day).

Present Continuous: I’m having lunch with Mary. (Means that I have the lunch with her NOW)

Incorrect: "I’ll be having lunch with Mary." - In this one, you should mention the time in order to make it correct Examples: **I will be playing tomorrow at 6:00.** or **I will be eating when you arrive.**

Comment: Why do you think that 'I'm having lunch with Mary' can be used only if we are talking about present? We can use the Present Continious for appointments and it will refer to the future in this case.